# AxesOrigin in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

Is there a way to change the origin of the axes in `ContourPlot`? I know that `Plot` the option of `AxesOrigin`, but what about `ContourPlot`?

Comment: `ContourPlot[..., Frame->False, Axes->True, AxesOrigin->{...}]`

Comment: The ContourPlot documentation does not show the AxesOrigin option under Options. However Options[ContourPlot] does show AxesOrigin by default set to Automatic.

Comment: `AxesOrigin` is an option to `Graphics`. Any `Graphics` option works with any function that produces a `Graphics` expression as output.